# making a ftp user with with permission for only one directory access

Tags: php, laravel

What I'm working on is a game panel. Basically what I did is, using SSH2 I established a connection from website to my vps, now what I'm trying to do is when I create a game server on my website I want to create a specific directory for that game server with a user that has only premissions to acces and upload files to that directory.

I've been trying to find a solution on google but I can't seem to find any. How can I do this? I'm using Laravel.

Comment: you want to make directory dynamically using Laravel?

Comment: Yes, a directory and a user that has permissions over that directory.

Comment: not sure about user, but we can make directory using Laravel.

Comment: I know about directories but I need a user for that directory, also created dinamically.

Comment: You would do this in the logic of your Laravel app, not by directory permissions on the file system.